# Разница между зависимостями в полях или свойствах

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования, dependency-injection, best-practice

У меня есть класс в который я передаю зависимость на конструктор, не могу понять как лучше сделать

Толи сохранить в поле:

```
public class Handler
{
    private readonly A _a;

    public Handler(A a)
    {
        this._a = a;
    }
}
```

Толи сохранить в свойство:

```
public class Handler
{
    private A A { get; }

    public Handler(A a)
    {
        this.A = a;
    }
}
```

Какой вариант лучше с точки зрения хороших практик?

Comment: private readonly A _a

Comment: Полностью приватное свойство обычно не имеет смысла. Для невычисляемого значения приватное свойство вообще бессмысленно